# Same output from combinations, comboGeneral and combn by converting matrix to list

Tags: r

I want to use combinations function from arrangements package and comboGeneral from RcppAlgos package to get the output having the same format as I get from combn function from utils package.

```
library(arrangements); library(magrittr); library(purrr); library(RcppAlgos)

comb1 <- map(1:2, ~combn(x=names(mtcars), m = .x, simplify=F)) %>% unlist(recursive = F)

comb2 <- map(1:2, ~combinations(names(mtcars), k = .x))

comb3 <- map(1:2, ~comboGeneral(names(mtcars), m = .x))
```

What do I need to do so that comb2 and comb3 have same format output as comb1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you may use

```
comb2 <- map(1:2, ~combinations(names(mtcars), k = .x) %>% split(row(.))) %>% unlist(recursive = FALSE)
comb3 <- map(1:2, ~comboGeneral(names(mtcars), m = .x, FUN = c)) %>% unlist(recursive = FALSE)
```

`comb2` happens to be a named list; if that's an issue, you may add extra `%>% unname`.

Comment: There is a shorter and faster solution for `arrangements::combinations`: `map(1:2, ~combinations(names(mtcars), layout = "l", k = .x)) %>% flatten()`